# Please document how to filter by obsolete or non-obsolete questions in search on Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, stack-overflow-for-teams, help-center

Neither the ["Search existing content" help page for Teams](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4400196-search-existing-content) nor the "Advanced Search Tips" Javascript toggle mentions the "Obsolete" status.

"Obsolete" is separate from "Closed", so using the closed status doesn't filter by obsolete status. Currently, searching returns both non-obsolete and obsolete questions, and as long as that's the case then obsolete is a useful status to search by.

Comment: By 'obsolete', do you mean that the questions are no longer relevant to current methods/environments/technologies, etc...? Or do you mean that the question itself is no longer appropriate for the site?

Comment: He means the "mark obsolete" feature on Teams, @ouflak.

Comment: To my understanding, the "Mark obsolete" button basically locks a post, adds a banner to it (that says "Obsolete. This question is obsolete because the content is out of date. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions."), and adds the text "[obsolete]" after the title in question listings. It doesn't seem like there's any other way to lock posts in Teams, so a search for `locked:yes` (just as on SO/SE) seems to return a list of posts that have been marked obsolete. (Of course, this could change in the future, but it seems to work for now.)

Comment: That said, the page you linked doesn't mention the `locked:` search parameter (though it does mention others like `closed:` and `duplicate:`). It should probably be added there.

Comment: @V2Blast We don't mention `locked:` there because it is not a usable feature in any of the post management menus within Teams (though you can technically trigger a locking with manual request forging). But there is an `obsolete:` search operator in Teams now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added the `obsolete:{boolean}` operator to the Teams help center article on searching. I'll leave it to the devs to determine whether it should also be added to the on-site toggle instructions since I can't edit those.

But it's also worth noting we should remove `wiki:no` and `migrated:no` from there since we don't support those features within Teams and they are irrelevant. So... while we're in there changing things, why not?